# What does $L^2$ on an arrow mean?

Tags: notation

This [post](https://www.statlect.com/asymptotic-theory/empirical-distribution) says

> If the $n$ observations in the sample
>   $$\xi_n = [x_1, \dots, x_n]$$
>   are the realizations of n mutually independent random variables  $X_1 \dots X_n$ having the distribution function $F_X(x)$, then

$$F_n(x)\stackrel{L^2}\to F(x)$$

for any $x \in R$

What does $L^2$ on an arrow mean? Does that mean "goes to" under some condition? If yes, what condition does the $L^2$ mean?

Comment: Converges within the [$L^2$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lp_space#Special_cases) norm most likely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it means it *goes to* something, i.e. it converges, and the *some condition* here is the $L^2$ -norm. $L^2$ is a [special case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lp_space#Special_cases) of the so-called [$L^p$-spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lp_space). Functions in $L^2$ are sometimes called [square integrable functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square-integrable_function) as for $f\in L^2(\Bbb R)$ we have that

> $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty |f(x)|^2\mathrm dx < \infty$$

The [$L^2$-norm](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/L2-Norm.html) is defined in a similiar manner, i.e.

> $$\|f\|_{L^2(\Bbb R)}:=\int_{-\infty}^\infty |f(x)|^2\mathrm dx$$

Comment: Thanks for your answer. How does the $L^2$ space affect the distribution? Does the distribution live in  the $L^2$ space?

Comment: @whnlp Yes. The equation given in the post you linked just states that $F_n$ converges to $F$ using the norm induced by $L^2$. Are you familiar with the concept of norms in general?

Comment: I know only a bit about Euclidean norm ~ I am afraid that I am not familiar with the concept of norms in general

Comment: @whnlp No problem at all! When working within real analysis we use (without thinking about it!) the [absolute value norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_(mathematics)#Absolute-value_norm) which enables us to, e.g. prove the convergence of a sequence. The aforementioned norm has some properties (the triangle inequalitiy for instance) which we utilize for our proofs. Here, the $L^2$-norm has for example a deep relation to integrals (by its very definition) which can be useful sometimes (e.g. in functional analysis when dealing with Fourier Transforms and similiar).

Comment: @whnlp So, long story short: a norm is a way of attaching "a value" to an "object" (don't take those terms to literally), but especially a [norm induces a metric](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Metric_Induced_by_Norm), that is a way of measuring distances and thus can be used for our good old $\varepsilon$-$\delta$-proof and much more!

Answer (score 1):

It means convergence in the $L^2$-norm, that is,
$$
\| F_n(x)-F(x)\|_{ L^2(\mathbb{R})  }\to 0
$$
as $n\to \infty $.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. How does the $L^2$ space affect the distribution? Does the distribution live in  the $L^2$ space?

Comment: Yes, and I reiterate @whnlp's answer.